# Simple Ajax request to a php url giving always an error

Tags: ajax, timeout

I am trying to get the data from my site with a simple php script. and trying to hit the url using ajax in fiddler but it always giving the error. can someone help in this .. I am very new to this.

here is the Fiddler url:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    log('document ready');

});
var i = 0;
function log(s) {
    $('#log').val($('#log').val() + '\n' + (++i) + ': ' + s);
}

var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "http://techiezhub.com/sample.php", function(data) {



  log( 'success'+data );

})
  .done(function() {
    log( 'second success' );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    log( 'error' );
  })
  .always(function() {
    log( 'complete' );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function() {
  log( 'second complete' );
});
```

Thanks
Yakub.

Comment: If you look at your console output you see this:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://techiezhub.com/sample.php. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This means your server does not allow requests from the jsfiddle.

Comment: can we able to enable it ?